# Debian - htacces 404 not found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian, apache2

I developed a site on wamp that works perfectly (.htaccess included).

so I deployed the site on a debian server, but I have the following error :

> 404 Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server.

here are the contents of my file :

```
#Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&param=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\_\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

all files belong to the user `www-data`.
`rewrite module` is enable.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your apache configuration.

On the virtualhost or default config you must **AllowOverride** to your domain or folder.

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
```

If you can not override your .htaccess is not going to work and if you can not rewrite the url you are accessing does not exists and you are going to get a 404 error.

Comment: glad that I helped !